# Google Over the Air installs server side flow redirect uri parameters are incorrect

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth, over-the-air

I have implemented google over the air installs using server side flow as mentioned in google's documentation:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

The client-side authentication is successful, but when I try to set the `redirect_uri` param to directly use my server endpoint, I see that there is an error in the params being returned.

I have configured my redirect_uri to be in this format:

`http://my_server/authenticate.html?param=value`

but what I get after redirection is:

`http://my_server/authenticate.html?param=value#login_hint=foo&code=bar`

as a result of this the url gets trimmed after the '#' when it hits my server and the code param is never being passed. Is this is a known issue in google sign-in for server side apps?